# sigmoidal curve with semilogx SciPy/Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have been working on fitting a negatively sloped sigmoidal trendline for a set of data. I have only been working on python for a week, sorry for the sloppy code. I have two sets of code which produce the data, however, I cannot get the sigmoid curve output as well.

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def sigmoid(x, x0, k):
     y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-(-k*(x-x0))))
     return y

x = [0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001, 0.000001]

y = [0.649097038, 0.682633434, 0.705470344, 0.749350609, 0.989377822, 0.972679201]


coefficients = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
polynomial = poly1d(coefficients)
xs = arange(0.000001, 0, 0.1)
ys = polynomial(xs)

curve_fit(sigmoid, x, y)

semilogx()

np.polyfit(x, y, 3, rcond=None, full=False, w=None, cov=False)

plot(x, y, 'o')
plot(xs, ys)
ylabel('Cell Viability')
xlabel('Concentration mM')
show()
```

.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sigmoid(x, x0, k):
     y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-(-k*(x-x0))))
     return y

xdata = np.array([0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001, 0.000001])
ydata = np.array([0.649097038, 0.682633434, 0.705470344, 0.749350609, 0.989377822, 0.972679201])

popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, xdata, ydata)
print popt

x = np.linspace(-10, 1, 50)
y = sigmoid(x, *popt)

semilogx()

pylab.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o', label='data')
pylab.plot(x,y, label='fit')
pylab.ylim(0, 1.05)
pylab.legend(loc='best')
pylab.show()
```

Comment: Ack, some tips first off - I would move away from the `from something import *` syntax ASAP.  It will make your life awful eventually.  Also, don't use pylab in programming code - use the correct thing that pylab wraps (numpy, scipy, etc).  Now, as to your question, it's not clear - what is actually wrong?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The problem is, when I run the first set of code through the kernel, the data point will show, however the trendline does not. The second set of code shows the data, and a trendline, however the trendline is skewed only after the last data point.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your two code pieces - some of which Ajean has hinted at. Let's carefully review what there is and what problems that causes.

**1st Code Block**

- Discard the first two lines and use only:

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
  ```

  Now, instead of `poly1d`, you'll have to call `np.poly1d`; instead of `semilogx()` it's `plt.semilogx()`; `plot`, `xlabel`, `ylabel` and `show` become `plt.plot`, etc.
- Next, your use of [`arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) returns an empty array. Instead, try this:

  ```
  np.arange(0.000001, 0.1, 0.000001)
  ```
- From [`curvefit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) you should actually store the returns, as your second code does:

  ```
  popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x, y)
  ```
- Next, use `sigmoid` to generate new `y`-values:

  ```
  ysig = sigmoid(x,*popt)
  ```
- If now you include an additional plot statement at the bottom, e.g.:

  ```
  plt.plot(x,ysig,'g')
  ```

  the output will be something like this:

  [image: output 1]

**2nd Code Block**

- It is sufficient to `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. Now, replace the `pylab.` occurrences with `plt.`
- However, all that does not really work, is the `linspace` command. If you try

  ```
  x = np.arange(0.000001, 0.1, 0.000001)
  ```

  instead, you'll get this output

  [image: output 2]

---

However, both approaches indicate that your fit does not really suit the data. But that may be a different question.

Comment: @text70 - does this answer work for you? If yes, please consider accepting it. If not, consider leaving a comment.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I have for code block 1.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def sigmoid(x, x0, k):
     y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-(-k*(x-x0))))
     return y

x = [0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001, 0.000001]

y = [0.649097038, 0.682633434, 0.705470344, 0.749350609, 0.989377822, 0.972679201]


coefficients = np.polyfit(x, y, 3)
polynomial = np.poly1d(coefficients)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x, y)

ysig = sigmoid(x, *popt)

plt.semilogx()
np.arange(0.000001, 0.1, 0.000001)

np.polyfit(x, y, 3, rcond=None, full=False, w=None, cov=False)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(x, ysig, 'g')
plt.ylabel('Cell Viability')
plt.xlabel('Concentration mM')
plt. show()
```

Comment: How does this answer your question? Please consider taking the tour. This is a strictly Q&A site, not a message board or forum. If my answer does not work for you, please leave a comment.